# Apache2 / Redirect to Subfolder w/ ReverseProxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, redirect, httpd, apache2

I am attempting to redirect / to a subfolder on an Apache2 reverse proxy server vhost for a server behind it. Reverse proxy is working, however the redirect is not. What would be the best way to do this? I am unable to configure the webserver behind the proxy to redirect.

```
# vhost *:80 > *:443 redirect

<VirtualHost *:80>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName hostname.domain.org
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyVia off
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/cert.key
        Redirect / hostname.domain.org/subfolder/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://hostname.domain.org/
        ProxyPass / https://hostname.domain.org/
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
        Header set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the 80 to 443 rewrite virtual host works, however redirect doesn't happen in the next virtual host https://hostname.domain.org to https://hostname.domain.org/subdirectory.